# Routing From Option Value React (Reacter Router)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

So I'm very new to React and I'm trying to figure out the best possible way to route to a different page when a user selects an option. In the code below, I have written the select itself, and it's state changes, but I'm having trouble even figuring out where to begin in routing this select to the new page.

```
var Header = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
     return {
         value: 'select'
     }
 },
 change: function(event){
     this.setState({value: event.target.value});
 },
 render: function(){
    return(
       <div>
           <select id="lang" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
              <option value='./Doctor.js'>Doctor</option>
              <option value='./Pharma.js'>Pharmacist</option>
              <option value='./Admin.js'>Admin</option>
           </select>
       </div>
    );
 }
});

export default Header
```

The values in the option value = are the routes im trying to figure out how to route. I've tried just using a  but got tons of errors. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

if you use `react-route`, you can try to use `this.props.history.push('/your route path')`;

and you need to change your `change` function

```
change: function(value){
  this.setState({value: value});
  this.props.history && this.props.history.push(`/your route/${value}`)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class List extends React.Component {
  //some stuff here
  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
        <li><Link to='/doctor'>Doctor page</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/pharmacist'>Pharmacist page</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/admin'>Admin page</Link></li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```